# XSS Page Cannot be Displayed

Tags: web-browser, xss, javascript, internet-explorer

When I try XSS on various websites, such as inserting `" onmouseover="alert(1)` in a search box, I either get a message saying `You don't have permission to access this page` or `This page cannot be displayed`. Is this because of the browser I am using (IE 11) or is it a method of defense against XSS?

Comment: Sounds like a server error, perhaps detecting invalid input.

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it happens in Chrome and IE 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one - "You don't have permission to access this page" - doesnt sound like the browser. The second - "This page cannot be displayed" - could be.

Different browsers react differently when they catch an XSS attack. If `mode=block` is set in the `X-XSS-Protection` header, both the latest version of Chrome and IE will give you a page similar to the one you get if you have no internet connection:

[image]

[Earlier version of IE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/01/31/controlling-the-xss-filter/) would give you a page containing only `#` and a warning dialog at the bottom of the page.

If `mode=block` is not set, both Chrome and IE will just quietly filter out the injected JavaScript and display the page without it.

If you want to test how a specific browser react, I recommend [this](http://www.enhanceie.com/test/xss/BlockMode.asp) great test page. Compare the error pages you got with what that site displays to know if it is the browser or not.

So if it is not the browser, what is it then? It is probably the page your are trying to exploit that has caught your XSS attempt and serves you a standard error page to fend off your attack. Or perhaps you caused an internal server error and the error page is a default fallback if that happends. It is impossible to know for sure what is going on behind the scenes on the server without having the source code it uses.